# What does the digit "1" mean when creating indexes in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

I am new to mongodb and want to make indexes for a specific collection. I have seen people use a digit "1" in front of the field name when they want to create an index. for example:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({user_name: 1})
```

now I want to know what does this digit mean and is it necessary to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defines the index type on that specefic field. For example the value of 1 creates an index with ascending order, while the value -1 create the index with descending order.

For more information, see the [Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/)

Comment: There are also the possible values `"hashed"`, `"text"`, `"2d"` and `"2dshphere"`.

Answer (score 4):

It's the type of index. MongoDB supports different kinds of indexes. However, only the first two indexes can be combined to a [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/).

- `1`: Ascending binary-tree index.
- `-1`: Descending binary-tree index. Very similar to the default index but [the difference can matter for the behavior of compound indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#index-ascending-and-descending).
- `"hashed"`: [A hashtable index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-hashed/). Very fast for lookup by exact value, especially in very large collections. But not usable for inexact queries ($gt, $regex or similar).
- `"text"`: A [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) designed for searching for words in strings with natural language.
- `"2d"`: A [geospatial index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) on a flat plane
- `"2dsphere"`: A [geospatial index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) on a sphere

For more information, see [the documentation of index types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/#index-type-list).